# Getting odd artifacting when using GPU preview on illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Shapes look as if they arent inline with each other when using GPU preview, CPU preview fixes the issue but of course I shouldnt have to be running it on CPU preview.They jaggies seem to stem from where there are anchor points, but not every anchor point.

**GPU Preview**

[image]

**CPU Preview**

[image]

Is this a bug or what, have I got some settings maybe causing it, when viewing it on my work PC it doesnt have these errors?

Comment: It's all due to the graphics processor. Nothing you can do except get a different GPU.

Comment: @Scott or turn it off...

Comment: Well yeah, Shixma figured that out though.. I thought he/she was asking how to fix the GPU preview specifically, which can only be done by using a different GPU :)